# Writing CSV file with SuperCSV in Linux platform

Tags: java, linux, unix, csv, supercsv

I am using SuperCSV for reading and writing csv files.
The problem i am facing is, under Unix/Linux systems, I am getting **"^M"** character appending to   end of each line, which is quite annoying.

How do I handle/fix that.

```
beanWriter = new CsvBeanWriter(new FileWriter(this.file), CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
final CellProcessor[] processors = getProcessors();
beanWriter.write(writeBean, header, processors);
```

part of code how I am exactly using SuperCSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the [docs](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/supercsv/prefs/CsvPreference.html) and [website](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/preferences.html) say, use `CsvPreference.EXCEL_PREFERENCE`.

Comment: I am checking that. Sorry, I missed that somehow before posting this question. But does it solve this problem?

Comment: It should! `CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE` includes a window-style carriage return (`\r`) which appears as `^M` on Linux. I just had to remove all of the carriage returns from the Super CSV [source code](https://sourceforge.net/p/supercsv/code/269/) (so I can develop it on Linux), so I feel your pain :)